# Quartz Scheduler's job fired but JobListener not picking up event?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

I have been struggling to make this work for a couple of days now. I am attempting to use the quartz scheduler to fire an event on my main form, from which a method can be called. Code on my main form is as follows:

```
void StartSchedule()
{
    string AuctionTime = "0 0 0 ? * MON-FRI *";

    JobKey jobkey = new JobKey("Auction", "G");

    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<AuctionJob>()
                                .WithIdentity(jobkey)
                                .Build();

    CronScheduleBuilder csb = CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule(new CronExpression(AuctionTime)).InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Local);

    ICronTrigger trigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                                        .WithIdentity("Auction-Trigger", "G")
                                                        .WithSchedule(csb)
                                                        .Build();

    // Create listener
    JobListener auctionListener = new JobListener();
    auctionListener.JobExecutedHandler += new EventHandler(SendAuctionOrders);
    IMatcher<JobKey> matcher = KeyMatcher<JobKey>.KeyEquals(jobkey);
    _scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(auctionlistener, matcher);

    // Add to scheduler
    DateTimeOffset ft = _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    LogEvent(job.Key + " scheduled at: " + ft.ToLocalTime());

    jobkey = new JobKey("Auction2", "G");

    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<AuctionJob>()
                                .WithIdentity(jobkey)
                                .Build();

    csb = CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule(new CronExpression(AuctionTime)).InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Local);

    ICronTrigger trigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                                        .WithIdentity("Auction-Trigger", "G")
                                                        .WithSchedule(csb)
                                                        .Build();

    // Create listener
    JobListener auction2Listener = new JobListener();
    auction2Listener.JobExecutedHandler += new EventHandler(SendAuctionOrders);
    IMatcher<JobKey> matcher = KeyMatcher<JobKey>.KeyEquals(jobkey);
    _scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(auction2listener, matcher);

    // Add to scheduler
    ft = _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    LogEvent(job.Key + " scheduled at: " + ft.ToLocalTime());

    _scheduler.Start();
}

void SendAuctionOrders()
{
    // Do something
}
```

AuctionJob class looks like this:

```
public class AuctionJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Empty
        Console.WriteLine("auction exec");
    }
}
```

While the job listener looks like this:

```
public class JobListener : IJobListener
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(JobListener));

    public event EventHandler JobExecutedHandler;

    public void JobExecutionVetoed(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        logger.Info("JobExecutionVetoed");
    }

    public void JobToBeExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        logger.Info("JobToBeExecuted");
    }

    public void JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException)
    {
        // Raise the event on executed
        OnJobExecuted(EventArgs.Empty);

        logger.Info("JobWasExecuted");
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "JobListener";
        }
    }

    // Event raiser
    protected virtual void OnJobExecuted(EventArgs args)
    {
        // This code will prevent IllegalThreadContext exceptions
        EventHandler jobExecHandler = JobExecutedHandler;

        if (jobExecHandler != null)
        {
            ISynchronizeInvoke target = jobExecHandler.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;

            if (target != null && target.InvokeRequired)
            {
                target.Invoke(jobExecHandler, new object[] { this, args });
            }
            else
            {
                jobExecHandler(this, args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the job is triggered, the job was executed (console prints "auction exec") but job listener's JobWasExecuted does not pick it up. Could anyone help me with this?

Additional questions: is there another way to call the main form's method? Also, would the job listener class persist through the entire application's (which in theory will not be closed). Thanks.

Comment: As I add more listeners to the Listener Manager, it seems like only the last listener actually raises the event. Strange.

Comment: Upon digging into the problem, when I add a new job listener, the old one gets wiped out under scheduler's globalJobListenersMatchers. How do I prevent this then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. When implementing IJobListener class, Name property is protected and when adding to ListenerManager, it overwrites the previous entry. Trick is to add a custom string when instantiating JobListener class and adding that to:

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return instanceName + "JobListener";
    }
}
```

Comment: I had this property but in my case it still didn't work. I changed AddJobListener to AddGlobalJobListener and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar today, where I had (log4net) debugging lines that were not outputting anything in my JobWasExecuted method, even though similar lines in JobToBeExecuted were working.  After beating on it for about two hours, I hacked my way out of it by raising a custom Exception after my job completed successfully.  (The "hack" part is having to raise an exception to get JobWasExecuted to react when I really just wanted to grab the final job status.)

I guess if I was doing this for a non-trivial project I'd just have my jobs drop messages onto a queue (and watch that), and it's possible I'm missing something I should be setting on my Jobs on the way out to raise an event, but I still found this part of the Quartz.NET world pretty messy.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was similar, but had a different cause - thought I'd share it here in case anyone else has the same problem. Events and listeners didn't seem to be firing. I was creating jobs/triggers dynamically, pulling the trigger start time from the database. The problem is that although the datetime I pulled from the database was UTC, it wasn't marked as UTC (but rather local) when used in C#. The jobs were getting scheduled, but for 9 hours in the future when I expected them to fire within a minute. Marking the datetimes as UTC fixed this:

```
DateTime NextExecutionStartDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(myDBObject.NextExecutionStartDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);

...Trigger.StartAt(NextExecutionStartDate)
```

instead of

```
...Trigger.StartAt(myDBObject.NextExecutionStartDate)
```